# Rails 4: Validate duplicates in a custom model validator

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this models:

## Ofert.rb

```
class Ofert < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :shipping_fees
end
```

## Shipping_fee.rb

```
class ShippingFee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :ofert
end
```

`ShippingFee` has an attribute `city`. I want to validate that user does not input the same city for the same `Ofert`

I already have it working like this:

```
class ShippingFee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :ofert
    validate :not_reapeated_cities

    def not_reapeated_cities
        ofert = Ofert.find self.ofert_id
        ofert.shipping_fees.each do |shipping_fee|
            errors.add(:city, "has been already added") if shipping_fee.city == self.city
            break if not errors.empty?
        end
    end
end
```

However I think there is a better way of do it, I want to optimize the app as much as possible. And when there are a lot of `ShippingFee`'s it won't be helpful for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `scope` option of the `uniqueness` validation like below

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :city, scope: :ofert_id
```

You also need to add an `unique index` to the `shipping_fees` table like below

```
add_index(:shipping_fees, [:city, :ofert_id], unique: true)
```

Comment: Hi I have a question, is the `add_index` strictly necessary?

Comment: @SsouLlesS Yes, for the sake of concurrency and integrity, you need to. For more info read this http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of